# DAGSTER: async ops and jobs and dynamic docker-ops

Tags: python, dagster

Here I have 2 questions.

1. I need to run an aiohttp session which shall simultaneously make several requests to different urls and download several files and return a list of absolute paths to these files on disk. This list shall be passed to another async function.

Is there a way to run an "async def" function within a dagster job and build an async pipeline?

2. In fact the length of the above mentioned list may differ from case to case. Each file requires a long and heavy processing and there is no way to make it async as the processing is blocking (unfortunately). So the only way is to start such processing in separate threads or processes or (as we do) - in separate docker-containers on different machines.

Can dagster dynamically create docker-containers with ops, return any output from them and kill each of them on container-exit?

Answer (score 1):

dagster supports both creating ops dynamically at runtime and running each op in its own container. You can read about dynamic mapping here: https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/jobs-graphs#dynamic-mapping--collect

And you can configure your job with an executor that has it run each op in its own container: https://docs.dagster.io/deployment/executors#executors (There's a docker_executor that would be a good fit if you're running on Docker, or a k8s_job_executor if you're on Kubernetes).

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell something about dagster and async?

Comment: @SergeyRybakov I don't think there's any reason you can't use async functions within an op as long as you collect the results within the op

Comment: @zyd so Ops are async by default?

Comment: ops are run in separate processes by default, using multiprocessing under the hood, so they are asynchronous in that respect. ops that don't have dependencies on each other (or are run using the dynamic mapping feature I linked) will be run concurrently in separate processes. within an op you can call whatever generic python code you want, so you could call functions defined with "async def" if you wanted to further parallelize within each op.

Comment: @zyd , no, ops are executed in blocking mode

Comment: @zar3bski - ops are executed in a subprocess when using the default multi process executor. They are executed synchronously, but you can use threading and async from within an op if you want concurrent threads running just within that op. There's nothing about how ops are called that will prevent you from using async or threads within the op. The op itself isn't called using async, but it will run in a process concurrent to any other ops which don't have a dependency on the op being ran.

Comment: @zyd , I think that the question did not concern the use of async **within** ops but **between** ops